# Energy Loss in Real Fluids and Pressure Drop

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

When real fluid flows in a pipe due to fluid's viscosity  pressure energy of fluid is converted to heat. What I don't quite understand is the mechanism in which this happens. When heat is created it inreases average kinetic energy of molecules in a fluid shouldn't that inrease fluid pressure since pressure of a fluid is connected to the average kinetic energy of its molecules. More energy they have they can transfer more momentum on pipe during collision and thus bigger pressure. I think  I don't quite understand what pressure of a fluid is as term in Bernoulli's equation, what causes it. Any constructive answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"Viscous Heating" is a bit of a misnomer.  When viscous deformational work is done on a fluid, the mechanical energy is converted, not into heat, but into internal energy.  Of course, for a gas, the internal energy increase is accompanied by a temperature increase, but the pressure does not have to increase if the specific volume increases.  In the case of a nearly incompressible liquid, changing the temperature does not need to directly affect the pressure.